# Webpack not accessible in Chrome debugger

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, debugging, webpack

I have been happily using the Chrome development tools for some five years to debug my Angular/node.js code. I open the Chrome development tools, click on the "sources" tab, navigate my way to the "Webpack" link on the left, and find my way to the directory of all my Javascript source and away we go. Among other matters, the good folk of Chrome have continually improved the debugger over the years: it is a beautiful thing. I have been very happy.

Until this week, when suddenly the Webpack disappeared from the source options. I can see lots else (essentially, all the javascript referenced direct from the index.html file) but the webpack is not there. Nor is it accessible in Safari. But it is still there in Opera and Firefox.

What is going on? I can not be the only person who routinely uses Chrome to debug a webpack application. Help, please.

Here is a screenshot of what I see in my browser. First, as it now appears WITHOUT any Webpack access, in Chrome:

[image: Debugger in Chrome, with no Webpack]

Second, as it still appears in Firefox (and Opera) with Webpack and all my stuff:

[image]

Update! I've found the code in Safari. But it no longer appears under the label "Webpack". Instead, it appears under the site URL-->dist-->app.bundle.js (which appears as a folder containing all the code files, thus:

[image]

However, app.bundle.js in Chrome is NOT a folder; clicking on it brings up this message:

[image]

Yes, I can see that I *might* here be able to use the "Filesystem" tab to import the files from my development system, and to edit and debug them directly in the debugger while running the app on a local host. Very neat. But actually, there are many times I need to be able to dig inside the app on the production system. I can still do this on Safari, Firefox, Opera. But not now on Chrome. Why not?

UPDATE! I have been digging yet further. Not only is it only Chrome that has this problem. It appears that it is only Chrome on an M1 chip Mac running Big Sur. And digging still deeper: when I look at the app.bundle.js file I discover -- lo and behold! -- all 13000 lines of my code, originally distributed across some 60 component.js files, appears in this one indigestible mega file. Yes, I could find the bit I am working on in there and debug it. So Chrome developers: how come the Safari folks are able to deconstruct app.bundle.js back to the original file structure and you guys cannot?

Comment: Yes it certainly is. After five years of using these tools everyday I know my way about it better than I know my way around my house.

Comment: OK added some screenshots. I'd be sorry to have to leave Chrome. But I'm really concerned that what Chrome is doing today, other browsers will do tomorrow.

Comment: tried that too. Is anyone else having this problem?

Comment: Edited the post: the problem appears unique to Chrome on major MacOS browsers. I have not been able to check in IE.

Comment: Did you ever get a resolution to this? Someone reported this same issue to me and is hoping for a solution.

Comment: DeborahK: no, I did NOT get a resolution, and indeed the problem persists. It's a huge pain in the neck.